# How to send JWT token to jQuery in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jwt

When user presses the login button, I redirect to usercontroller.php and obtain jwt token from API.

```
$result = $this->obtainAccessToken($request->email, $request->password);
```

then I put the JWT token and user info to session.

```
Session::put('user', $result);
```

then redirect user to home page.

```
return redirect(route('home'));
```

Everything is ok.

I can access that token and user info in view (blade) pages using

```
Session::get('user');
```

But sometimes I need to request jQuery ajax to server. But I dont have token info in my js files. How can I send that token info which is stored in session to js files?

Also I tried to store that info in Cookie like;

```
Cookie::queue('user', $result, 10);
```

But I couldn't access in jQuery using;

```
$.Cookie('user');
```

it returns undefined.

**UPDATE**

I found a way something like this;

```
<meta name="token" content="{{ Session::get('user')->token }} />
```

and access using jQuery

```
$('meta[name=token]').attr('content);
```

---

> but is it safe method?

---

Comment: I don't know what a JWT token is. *If* it must not be publicly displayed, then there is no safe way to pass it to any AJAX call. Otherwise it's good :)

Comment: A jwt token is a common json web token which is send with a request. There exists a package called "jwt-auth".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
but is it safe method?
```

Yes, it is. It's the common way you would also choose if you do a ajax-request on your api.

The only thing that could happen is, that the api returns an error code 219 (session expired), when the token is false.

Cheers,

Niklas